# Getting MySQL syntax error after submitting the form

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I wrote a simple java code to accept the parameters from a form and store it in a table. Here is the code:

```
String fname = request.getParameter("username");
String mail = request.getParameter("email");
String country = request.getParameter("country");
String pword = request.getParameter("password");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foodforthought", "root",
        "********");                                            
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
try {
    int i = statement.executeUpdate("insert into users (username,email,country,password) values ("+fname+"','"+mail+"','"+country+"','"+pword+")");
    out.println("Successfully registered");
} catch (Exception e) {
    out.println(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**`Error:`**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'India',')' at line 1
```

The value of country is `India` which is coming from the form. How can I fix it?

Comment: You are missing quotes after the first parenthesis and before the last one of the `values` part. Better use `PreparedStatement` to avoid this problem and possible injection.

Comment: `'"+pword+"` you are missing a single quote in the end.

Comment: `int i = statement.executeUpdate("insert into users (username,email,country,password) values ('"+fname+"','"+mail+"','"+country+"','"+pword+"')");`

Answer (score 3):

Your single quotes are wrong.

But never use the value readed from a form to insert into your database, you could be suffer SQL injection

http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_injection.asp

Use prepared statements where the parameters are properly parsed to the specific type

An example:

```
  String query = "insert into dept(deptnum, deptname, deptloc) values(?, ?, ?)";
  PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
  pstmt.setInt(1, 1); // set input parameter 1
  pstmt.setString(2, "deptname"); // set input parameter 2
  pstmt.setString(3, "deptLocation"); // set input parameter 3
  pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute insert statement
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten `'` characters in your query:

```
("+fname+"','"+mail+"','"+country+"','"+pword+")
 ^ here                              and here ^
```

Change it to `('"+fname+"','"+mail+"','"+country+"','"+pword+"')`

Or better use `PreparedStatement` to avoid this kind of mistakes and SQL injection issue as well.

```
String sql = "insert into users (username, email, country, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql); 

// Insert values safe and indirectly to avoid mistakes and SQL injection
preparedStatement.setString(1, fname);
preparedStatement.setString(2, mail);
preparedStatement.setString(3, country);
preparedStatement.setString(4, pword);

// Perform the update
int count = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: The line `ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();` gives an error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to ResultSet`

Comment: Right, I've made a mistake. Thank you :)

Comment: Now, it throws another error: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'`

Comment: It means you are missing the column `username` in your databse or it's wrong in the SQL statement (that's noone can know). Plase correct it. Moreover it is not related to my answer.